# How can I avoid rebuilding current conan package?

Tags: c, conan

I am using Conan to build some C packages, and Conan install manages well to retrieve my dependencies matching the current environment without the need to rebuild them from source.

But how can I have the same behavior for the current package? I mean, if no dependencies have changed, if the source code has not changed, I would like `conan install` to notify me somehow that the steps `conan build/export` is not useful since the exact same result is already available on the remote.

Is it possible to have this behavior with Conan?

Comment: Not sure exactly what is your problem. Doing ``conan create . --build=missing`` will indeed export the package to the cache and then it will only create the package if it is missing, but it will re-use the binary in the server if it exists. Maybe you want to file a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues for further clarification.

Comment: For the dependencies, yes, it works, but what I am looking for is a way to avoid rebuilding the current package if nothing has changed (.c, .h, dependencies as well).